# Version control application on noSQL DB

Tags: mongodb, version-control, nosql, versioning, aws-documentdb

I am working on the design of an application that is going to work on data collected on DocumentDB.
Assume I have a single data structure structure (json representing a product). This product is going to be altered by multiple actors, external fluxes etc
So each time an actor alters a field a new version for the product is created.

What I have now to produce is an application that works on this data, enabling merging features/version management, in order to have an administration user that can produce a new data version, connecting each piece. Something like git , you can rollback, merge, insert new data, approve an edit ..

Do you have any suggestion on a service on AWS, or a library that can help the development on this side?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thinking at schema design, you could try the [document versioning pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern).